# translating a counter from python to R

Tags: python, r

I want to translate this to R

```
for d in DMF {}
if d < 12 {}
count <- count + 1
count <- 0
else {continue}
count <- count / 2
```

d is distance values in the DMF dataset
I want to set a count for each time there is a value d < 12
I am very lost. Any help appreciated

Comment: Your code looks like R instead of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is to get the number of element that are less than 12

```
sum(DMF < 12, na.rm = TRUE)
```